# System Overflow Int16 Error in C# on German PCs

Tags: c#, integer, converters

I am having a bit of an issue here. I have a snippet below of an application that has been working just fine on PC's throughout the world of the USA, UK, South Africa, and Australia. However, on two German colleagues machines, this following code fails with an error of:

> System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int16.

This is happening at the Convert.ToInt16 steps. I am wondering if this can be caused by the decimal system in Germany being comma's as opposed to periods? Also, the fieldItemsValues value for the example is:

> [InputText_confirmName,0,2,49.5216,726.6744,303.2712,47.9664,false,0,0,false,0]

All strings

```
string[] widgetProperties = fieldItemValues[0].Split('_');
string widgetType = widgetProperties[0];
string widgetID = widgetProperties[1];
Console.WriteLine("Type: " + widgetType + " ID: " + widgetID);

float widgetLeft = Convert.ToSingle(fieldItemValues[3]);
float widgetTop = Convert.ToSingle(fieldItemValues[4]);
float widgetWidth = Convert.ToSingle(fieldItemValues[5]);
float widgetHeight = Convert.ToSingle(fieldItemValues[6]);

int widgetLeftPx = Convert.ToInt16(widgetLeft * 2.0);
int widgetTopPx = Convert.ToInt16(widgetTop * 2.0);
int widgetWidthPx = Convert.ToInt16(widgetWidth * 2.0);
int widgetHeightPx = Convert.ToInt16(widgetHeight * 2.0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess here's your problem: 726.6744

In german notation, "." is the thousands separator, not the comma - you have to add a locale. so the english 726.6744 becomes 7,266,744.00

Comment: That is a great idea. Unfortunately, I am not completely well versed in localization of code. Would this locale setting have to be done for each offending line of code? Or can this be a global setting for the application to convert based on locale?

Comment: Where are those strings coming from? Entered by the user?

Comment: Parsed from a "Metadata" file that our software at our company creates on the fly. Can be different at all times. I was thinking of doing something like:

float widgetLeft = Convert.ToSingle(fieldItemValues[3], new CultureInfo("en-US"));
float widgetTop = Convert.ToSingle(fieldItemValues[4], new CultureInfo("en-US"));
float widgetWidth = Convert.ToSingle(fieldItemValues[5], new CultureInfo("en-US"));
float widgetHeight = Convert.ToSingle(fieldItemValues[6], new CultureInfo("en-US"));

Comment: as long as you know which format to expect and the metadata file contains strings in en-us, this should work

Comment: `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` (equals to `new Culture("")`) is more consistent and readable and won't be tied to any specific country or region. 

One uses new CultureInfo("ll-cc") only when parsing user input or formating values user interface in his preferred culture (P.S. It's called internationalization (formatting settings), or i18n for short. Localization (or L10n) is used for translations)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
Convert.ToInt16(widgetLeft * 2.0);
```

to

```
NumberStyles style = style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands;
Int16.Parse(widgetLeft * 2.0, style, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can read more about the NumberStyles [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx)  and about culture info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx)

Comment: Interesting I will try this too. Thanks for your input

Comment: there's a small error - the int16 needs no parsing - the float needs to be changed (widgetlegt is already a float - shouldn't be a problem)